# Unable to retrieve data from Firebase database with new SDK

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a call to retrieve a dictionary of data from Firebase.

```
 reference().child("recipes").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
   let recipes = snapshot.value[week] as? [[String:AnyObject]]
})
```

The problem is that I get the error "Type 'AnyObject?' has no subscript members on snapshot.value[week]. In the Firebase docs they subscript to find the value they want:

```
ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
  // Get user value
  let username = snapshot.value!["username"] as! String
  let user = User.init(username: username)
})
```

In my code you'll notice I am not using the ! because I prefer not to use them. However when I edited my code to use it the same way they have in their examples, to test if I could subscript if I copied it exactly, I get a build error: Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Have you used the new SDK and if so how did you retrieve data?

Comment: did you mean "week" and not week ?

Comment: the variable week is a a string that says what week it is (for example "week5")